# Populating a table from a file only last column is populated JavaFX

Tags: file, javafx, tableview, scenebuilder

I am struggling with populating all columns for a table after reading data from a file.  Only the last column is being populated. I fear it is something simple, but cannot see where the error is.  I have read many other examples and have watched several youtube videos.  My code is as follows:

PhoneBook Class:

```
public class PhoneBook {
private SimpleStringProperty lastNm;
private SimpleStringProperty firstNm;
private SimpleStringProperty phoneNum;

public PhoneBook(String last, String first, String num)
{
    lastNm = new SimpleStringProperty(last);
    firstNm = new SimpleStringProperty(first);
    phoneNum = new SimpleStringProperty( "("+num.substring(0, 3)+ ") " +num.substring(3, 6) +
            "-" +num.substring(6));
}

public String getLast()
{
    return lastNm.get();
}

public String getFirst()
{
    return firstNm.get();
}
public String getPhoneNum()
{
    return phoneNum.get();
}

public void setLast(String last)
{
    lastNm = new SimpleStringProperty(last);
}

public void setFirst(String first)
{
    firstNm = new SimpleStringProperty(first);
}
public void setPhoneNum(String num)
{
    phoneNum = new SimpleStringProperty(num);
}
```

}

Controller code:

```
public class ListExampleController  implements Initializable{

@FXML
private TableView<PhoneBook> tblView;
@FXML
private TableColumn<PhoneBook, String> colLastNm;
@FXML
private TableColumn<PhoneBook, String> colFirstNm;
@FXML
private TableColumn<PhoneBook, String> colPhoneNum;

public ArrayList <PhoneBook> book = new ArrayList<>();
public ObservableList <PhoneBook> bookList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(book); 

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    ArrayList <PhoneBook> book = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        // Create an Array list of data
        book = readPhoneBk();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ListExampleController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    ObservableList <PhoneBook> bookList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(book);
    colLastNm.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PhoneBook, String>("lastNm"));
    colFirstNm.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PhoneBook, String>("firstNm"));
    colPhoneNum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PhoneBook, String>("phoneNum"));

    tblView.setItems(bookList);
}

public ArrayList<PhoneBook> readPhoneBk() throws IOException
{
    // Open the file
    String fileName = "phoneBook.txt";
    File file = new File(fileName);
    ArrayList<PhoneBook> book = new ArrayList();

    try ( // Create a Scanner object for file input
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            String str = inputFile.nextLine();
            // Get the tokens from the string
            String[ ] tokens = str.split("\t") ;

            book.add(new PhoneBook (tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2]));
        }
        // Close the file
    }

    return book;
}
```

}

Comment: See linked (duplicate) question - the values passed to `PropertyValueFactory` should match the names of the getter/setter, regardless of the field name of the actual property (there may not even be one!)

Comment: wow! I saw this and only thought it was a typo with the "s"...NOT the fact that the getter and setter HAD to have the exact field names with get and set added. So very thankful for your explanation! It was extremely clear.